# thyroid stimulating hormone levels and thyroid

Tags: thyroid, tsh-levels

I recently got myself tested for my T3 levels and TSH too as I usually developed hand tremors and fast heart beats at sudden occasions. I am 18 yo. My TSH level is **5.21 μIU/ml**. According to me, the refrence ramge is 0.3-5.5 but thats brings me on the threshold. Should I consider medicines? or diet? If any?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We can't make a diagnosis or make personal recommendations over the internet, it has to be done by a physician in person. This is why personal medical advice is off-topic for this site.The doctor will use your blood test results, along with the anamnesis and if needed other tests to do that.

Comment: This is probably best discussed with your doctor.